# Delete from Link Dynamically named form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the form name to the function and then confirm they are read to delete it after that I want to change the action then submit the form.

```
function deletePhone(myForm){
   var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?');
   if(r==true){
       $(myForm).attr("action","index.cfm?deleteThis=1");
       $(myForm).submit();
   }
}
```

currentrow is a variable that I am using because I am creating multiple forms and it holds the currentCount for the form.

```
   <a href="javascript:deletePhone('EditPhone_form_#currentrow#');">X Delete Phone</a>
```

**Example:**

- EditPhone_form_1
- EditPhone_form_2
- EditPhone_form_3
- EditPhone_form_4

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What is the question? What errors do you get?

Comment: how is your HTML markup look like? you could bind your a-elements and use jQuery .closest() to find the closest form from your a-element and change its action, and remember that you can chain your jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you're doing the jQuery lookup based on the ID, it isn't formatted correctly.

Try this:

```
   function deletePhone(myForm){
       var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?');
       if(r==true){
          $('#'+myForm).attr("action","index.cfm?deleteThis=1");
          $('#'+myForm).submit();
       }
    }
```

**Note the extra # added**

Edit:
You haven't posted the whole HTML of the form, but presumably the  tag is in the form itself, right? If yes, then you could also try this:

`<a href="javascript:deletePhone($(this));">X Delete Phone</a>`

```
   function deletePhone(link){
       var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?');
       if(r==true){
          var form = link.closest('form');
          form.attr("action","index.cfm?deleteThis=1");
          form.submit();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple and sorry... I left out that was the ID of the form as well as the name.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing action you can add a hidden field in form. And you should use `$("[name='"+myForm+"']")` to element if `myForm` is name of form.

```
$("[name='"+myForm+"']").append("<input type='hidden' value=1 name=deleteThis />");
```

so your code will be.

```
 function deletePhone(myForm){
       var r=confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?');
       if(r==true){
          $("[name='"+myForm+"']").append("<input type='hidden' value=1 name=deleteThis />");
          $("[name='"+myForm+"']").submit();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather see you use jQuery event binding instead of using the onclick event:

```
function deletePhone(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this phone?');
    if(r){
        $(this)
            .closest('form')
            .attr("action","index.cfm?deleteThis=1")
            .submit();
    }
}

$(".remove-phone").on("click", deletePhone);
```

and use a markup like:

```
<a href="#" class="remove-phone">X Delete Phone</a>
```